# How to Host JSON file in URL without any spaces in it?

Tags: javascript, json, url, hosting

I have .json file which needs to be taken for a program through URL. I have it locally in my PC. I want to geet it from URL. I tried using myjson.com but when I try to paste JSON file in it I couldn't do it correctly. Everything in it is being pasted to URL without any spaces. So I couldn't use that URL.

As, I told I used myjson.com but I couldn't paste it there without any spaces.
Check it out in below link.

https://api.myjson.com/bins/1g5r6x

Comment: Your json looks valid to me. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Why worry about JSON formatting. Its a valid JSON and better served compressed to save bandwidth

Comment: If spaces *inside quoted values* were being thrown away, I'd worry about that, but that doesn't seem to be a problem. Only purely optional formatting spaces are being removed. You can always re-stringify the JSON data if you want to put spaces back into it.

Comment: But,I get errors when I try to access this JSON file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

you can paste it raw and have it as a JSON format